# multidimensional Judy array

Tags: php, arrays, json, judy-array

Im trying to adapt Judy into my code using it almost as a conventional php array but i am having a bad time trying to access the multidimensional array. Everytime i try to print a nested key value i get a NULL.

1. how can i iterate through my results?
2. how can i encode this structure into a json? Everytime i try, i get a empty bracets "{}"

My code:

```
/**
 * This method parses the content of XML body
 * Array of objects to spare more memory usage
 * @param $xml object SimpleXml Object
 * @param $timeRequest array this second param brings the time_request value along with the url
 */
private function parseXmlContent($xml, $timeRequest)
{
    $counter = 0;
    $forecast = new \Judy(Judy::INT_TO_MIXED);

    foreach ($xml->point as $key => $value):

        $forecast[$counter] = $this->initJudy($value, $timeRequest, count($value);            
        $counter++;

    endforeach;

    $this->sucess++;
    $this->results[$this->results->nextEmpty(0)] = $forecast;
}

private function initJudy($value, $timeRequest, $length)
{
    $judy = new \Judy(Judy::STRING_TO_MIXED);
    $judy['timestamp'] = (string)$value->data[0];
    $judy['time_request'] = $timeRequest[0]->time_request;
    $judy['latitude'] = (string)$value->data[1];
    $judy['longitude'] = (string)$value->data[2];

    $j = 0;
    for ($i = 3; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $attribute = $this->variables[$j];
        $judy[$attribute] = (string)$value->data[$i];
        $j++;
    }

    return $judy;

}
```

Comment: `json_encode($this->results);` or whatever you want to pass as a JSON data structure see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly i changed the structure and now im working with something along this:  `$judy[INT] = new Judy(STRING_TO_MIXED);` using json_encode function returns a empty `{}`